# using htaccess and php setcookie to deflect brute force joomla attacks

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm attempting to deflect brute force attacks on joomla installations by making the administrator folder unavailable using an index.php file in folder x:

```
<?php

$admin_cookie_code= "cTlD56DcD0d2dVr982";

setcookie("AdminAccess", $admin_cookie_code, 0, "/");

header("Location: /administrator/index.php");

?>
```

in combination with the .htacces file in the root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !AdminAccess=cTlD56DcD0d2dVr982
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Now, mind you folder x is password protected, so in order to set the cookie you need a password. However, the result of the above is that it works when you go through folder x (you get redirected to the administrator folder as intended), but it doesn't prevent going to the administrator folder directly, which should give the 404...

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks, Marty